# How do I prevent "No Internet calling account" error?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, phone-app, sip

I'm running 2.3-Gingerbread.
Calling was working fine over the telephone network.
I set up the internet calling feature by adding an account to test the featuire out.
Then I removed the account.
Every time I dial a number I get this error:

```
No Internet calling account
There are no Internet calling accounts on this phone. Add one now?
```

If I click cancel, it doesn't dial using the telephone network it just returns to the home screen.

I've cleared the defaults for the Dialer application but still the problem persists.

Does anyone know how I can prevent this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have an app called "Voice Changer" installed? I've read that it can cause this. Also if you have google voice installed, do you have it set to "Never Dial with Google Voice"?

If those are not the cause, do you have any other "Phone Linking" apps or "Sip Dialers" etc, remove them and see if your issue stops.

Comment: Had a SIP app. Disabling it seemed to do the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same problem. Try this: go to Settings; Call; Use Internet Calling; and select the middle option: Only for Internet calls. I haven't encountered the problem since I did this. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

While I don't have the Nexus S, so can't say for sure, but my guess is that you've accidentally made Internet Calling the default action for dialing a number. Go to settings> applications> manage applications and clear defaults on the Internet calling application, not the dialer.

Comment: Actually running on HTC Magic! Thanks for your suggestion. I tried it but there is no 'Internet calling' application.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings >> Applications >> Manage applications >> All >> Dialer.
Under "Launch by default" press the "Clear defaults" button.

Answer (score 1):

Ok.. so heres the poop.
Settings >> Call >> Use Internet Calling
Change this setting to  " Only for Internet Calls"
Also Change
WI-Fi Calling to Disabled

For some reason if you use internet calling it defaults these settings to use it all the time even when you dont want it.

Answer (score 0):

I had Voice Changer installed and the second I uninstalled that it worked. Also go to Settings -> Call and go to the bottom and hit "Only for Internet Calls".