# Right swipe on contact defaulting to internet calls

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, calls, 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-s-3

My problem is: **right swipe is defaulting to internet calls instead of 'regular' calls**.

First off, these are my relevant call settings:
[image: User internet calling only for internet calls]

[image: No internet calling accounts]

as you can see I have no accounts and the internet calls are not enabled.

My contacts came from Google contacts (configured them online and then the phone got them).

After they came I used the "Mark as Default" function to select the correct phone number and emails and that's when things started behaving strangely. Doing a right swipe showed me this:

[image]

Instead of calling the contact 'normally'.

I started experimenting and was able to reproduce the bug using other similar contacts (contacts that I got from Google with 2 phone numbers + 2 emails). But if I created the Google contact locally (which would sync Ok with google) I didn't have any issues.

No other calling functions are affected: moving the phone to my ear still calls the correct number, direct dial widget still works.

My phone is a Galaxy S III running android 4.1 (but the same thing was already happening in 4.0), if that makes any difference.

**What is causing this? How can I fix it?**

Seems to be related to: [How do I prevent "No Internet calling account" error?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6489/how-do-i-prevent-no-internet-calling-account-error) but I was still unable to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tldr: I have found a <strike>solution</strike> work-around:

1. Go to google contacts in your browser and remove the emails from the contact (you can put them in the notes to avoid losing them).
2. Let it sync with your phone.
3. Add emails back to the contact (still from the browser).

You can now do all the "Mark as Default" you want because it will keep calling correctly.

---

Long version:

I decided to do some other experiments.

I started by creating a contact specifically for this (with 2 fake phone numbers and 2 fake emails) and let 
it sync with my phone. Used "Mark as Default" to select just the phone number.

[image: Mark default phone number]
[image: Default phone number marked]

It kept working fine. Then I selected the default email.

[image: Mark default phone number and email]
[image: Default phone number and email marked]

Thats when the phone **started to try to make internet calls**.

To continue my experiments I needed to deselect the email (which is not possible from the phone), 
so I went to google contacts from my browser and removed the emails and let it sync with my phone.

[image: Move contact emails to notes]

I then re-added the emails.

[image: Move emails back to contact]

To my surprise the issue vanished completely for that contact.

Sure enough I did the same for my problematic contacts and everything is fine now. :)

Answer (score 3):

Mr. Portela has it right, and I figured out a way to solve the issue more quickly:

1. Select the misbehaving contact.
2. Long press the 'default' email address.
3. Select 'Clear default'.

Voila.

I'm not sure what will happen when you try to email these contacts from now on, but at least calling works as intended.